# How to remove end of string with special characters?

Tags: php

I have string like

```
Clothing, Shoes & Accessories:Men's Clothing:T-Shirts
```

I want to remove end of string like T-Shirts.
And result should be

```
Clothing, Shoes & Accessories:Men's Clothing
```

I am using

```
end(explode(':',"Clothing, Shoes & Accessories:Men's Clothing:T-Shirts"));
```

But I am getting only T-Shirts

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to keep? The Clothing or the T-Shirt part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple regex:

```
<?php
$string = "Clothing, Shoes & Accessories:Men's Clothing:T-Shirts";
$regex = '~:[^:]*$~';
$string = preg_replace($regex, '', $string);
echo $string;
# Clothing, Shoes & Accessories:Men's Clothing   
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

From what you've mentioned, looks like after exploding, you need to remove the last array element. This is where [array_pop()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) function comes in handy.

It will remove the last element. And then try one more step and implode your array.

Try this:

```
$arr = explode(':', $string);
array_pop($arr);
echo implode(':', $arr);  // Clothing, Shoes & Accessories:Men's Clothing
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so your explode() function is working as expected, and splitting the string into a set of shorter strings and stuffing them into an array.

The end() function returns the last element of an array, which is why you are getting the result of only seeing the text section which was last.  What you actually want to do is get every section *except* for the last one back, right?

You can do this by recombining the array back into a string, but without its final member, if you want to keep going down the path you seem to be on:

```
// Set the string with initial content
$string = "Clothing, Shoes & Accessories:Men's Clothing:T-Shirts";
// Explode the string into an array with 3 elements
$testArray = explode(':', $string);
// Make a new array from the old one, leaving off the last element
$slicedArray = array_slice($testArray, 0, -1);  
// Implode the array back down to a string
$newString = implode(':', $slicedArray);
```

It would probably be easier to search for the last occurance of the separator character and remove any characters in the string from there on, but I'm not sure if that fits your use-case or not.  For completeness, you'd probably do it something like this:

```
// Set string with content
$string = "Clothing, Shoes & Accessories:Men's Clothing:T-Shirts";
// Get index of last : character in the string
$lastIndex = strrpos($string, ':');
// Set new string to left portion of original string up til last : char
$newString = substr($string, 0, $lastIndex);
```